# Filtering DataGridView by FK in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the following database structure:

`T_CUSTOMER: ID (PK), F_NAME varchar`

`T_ORDERS: ID (PK), ID_CUSTOMER (FK), F_ORDER_DATE datetime`

The `DataGridView` displays data from table `T_ORDERS`, and I would like to be able to filter and sort results by customer name `("F_NAME LIKE '% s%', 'ORDER BY F_NAME')`.

All I can do is filter and sort the `ID_CUSTOMER` column that contains values numbers. How can most easily make this type of filter for a column containing a foreign key, and being a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: You could create a `View` that links the two tables?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server CE. It is not possible to create a view, plus I'd like to be able to edit the data in the DataGridView. I tried by modifying the TableAdapter and used Usage INNER JOIN. However, this method seems to be very confusing. I'm looking for something simpler.